# outlook vba calling an Excel dialog.show fails

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, dialog, runtime-error

I have an Outlook macro that's failing with a run-time error 1004 "show method of dialog class failed" on line:

```
xlApp.Dialogs(xlDialogColorPalette).Show
```

The relevant parts of code (or so I think) are:

```
Private WithEvents oExpl As Explorer
Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem
Private WithEvents respItem As MailItem
Private xlApp As Excel.Application

Private bDiscardEvents As Boolean


Private Sub Application_Startup()

   Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")    

   Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
   bDiscardEvents = False

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub respItem_Send(cancel As Boolean)    

   bDiscardEvents = True

    Dim orgbody As String       
    orgbody = respItem.HTMLBody


    xlApp.Dialogs(xlDialogColorPalette).Show
```

Thanks a many!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some minimal code, that would work out, following the idea with public `xlApp` variable:

```
Option Explicit

Private xlApp As Excel.Application

Sub TestMe()

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Dim someWb As Workbook
    Set someWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlApp.Visible = True

    If xlApp.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(56) Then
        someWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Interior.Color = ActiveWorkbook.Colors(56)
    End If

End Sub
```

---

These are the parameters of `xlDialogEditColor` - color_num, red_value, green_value, blue_value

- [MSDN Built-In Dialog Box Argument Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/built-in-dialog-box-argument-lists)

Comment: After calling this sub I get a Run-time err '438' - object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: thanks, it solved the problem of the color picker not appearing. Apparently you have to add the workbook so it works. On the other hand, the color picker appears in background and when I select a color, he brings up the workbook in front which I don't want, as I'm working with Outlook and need Excel only for the color picker.

Comment: @stevica - you can probably try with `xlApp.Visible = False` (although Idk whether the color picker would be shown in that case, cannot try it now)

Comment: May I ask why do I need to add a Workbook in order to be able to use this dialog, since the dialog is a member of Application class and not of Workbook? Sorry if it's a dumb question but I'm a novice...

Comment: @stevica - I am using the workbook only to write to its range whatever is selected - `someWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Interior.Color`